# How to read this line in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, directory

I came across the following lines in `MATLAB`:

```
m = dir(fullfile(dataset,'*.png'));
m = {m(~[m.isdir]).name};
```

I understand that the first line is trying to obtain the `.png` files from a directory. But, what is the second line trying to perform? `isdir` seems to determine that an input is a directory. That's what I new for that part. But, what is the line trying to perform?

Thanks.

Comment: please consider accepting an answer or updating your question to let people know that an solution was found so they may use this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The second line is getting all files that are not a directory and then getting the respective names and storing them into a cell array

- `m.isdir` indicates if it is a folder or not

  - returns 1 if it is, 0 if not.
- `~[m.isdir]` will indicate which of the values returned from `isdir` was a 0.
- `m(~[m.isdir])` grabs all objects in m determined by the logical indexing done above
- `m(~[m.isdir]).name` gets the names of all of them
- `{m(~[m.isdir]).name}` stores them all in cell array

Hopefully this step by step walkthrough helps.

While I am not sure why the second line is necessary because the `fullfile(dataset,'*.png')` should only return paths that end in `.png`, which will not be a folder, I guess it is good to check.

Comment: I agree that this is what the code does. However, I'm not sure why it's there, because the previous line of code should define `m` using only .png files.

Comment: I just edited my posted stating the same thing. I guess you could technically be tricky and name a folder as `something.png` but I don't see that situation ever really occurring